# Open project without frontend_dev.php

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I created project in Symfony 1.4 and upload on FTP.
If i open http://mysite.com/frontend_dev.php/login or http://mysite.com/frontend_dev.php/manage then all working OK, but if i open http://mysite.com/login or http://mysite.com/manage then i have error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Why? What i must change in Symfony or Apache?

Comment: Did you follow each step from [this tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration)?

Comment: Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and that you uploaded the .htaccess file in symfony's web directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `frontend/config/setting.yml` you have 4 env by default:

- prod
- dev
- test
- all

Add this lines

```
dev:
  .settings:
    no_script_name: true  # means you don't need the frontend_dev.php in url
```

Then clear cache `php symfony cc` and test.

Also, check that "`all`" env doesn't overwrite `no_script_name:`.

Hope this information useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
no_script_name: true
```

in the prod sections of your settings.yml, 
and:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

in htaccess?

If not, than use this.
It will work, just change the RewriteRule according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you run "symfony cc" on the server. The dev environment clears the cache on every page load but that's not true for production. If you've changed routes, you'll always need a "symfony cc" afterwards.